# ejabberdctl mod_http_bind module not available

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, candy

I'm trying to install candychat on top ejabberd, so I follow the [instructions](https://github.com/candy-chat/candy/wiki/Installing-a-XMPP-server) and try to install `mod_http_bind`.

However the module seems not available anymore

```
ejabberdctl module_install mod_http_bind
Error: not_available
```

The node's version:

```
ejabberdctl status
The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
ejabberd 18.12.1-2 is running in that node
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_http_bind was included in ejabberd, and later it was renamed to mod_bosh.